# JavaScript for resizing photos in Blogger posts

Tags: javascript, image, blogger

I am trying to automate resizing of photos in Blogger posts (without much luck). Basically I need a piece of JavaScript that would

- find all  elements
- within each of the elements above find all  elements

these are of the form:

```
<img style="display:block; margin:0px auto 10px; text-align:center;cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;width: 400px; height: 265px;" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y8j5IluAe4g/TykduAo1gnI/AAAAAAAAD38/K6VakbKwowU/s400/Czerwony%2BStompee%2Bdla%2Bdzieci.jpeg" alt="" id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5704123079323910770" border="0" />
```

For every one of these I need to:

- change `width: 400px;` to `width: 556px;`
- remove `height: 256px;`
- change the string `/s400/` in the link to `/s556/`

So after the changes I get:

```
<img style="display:block; margin:0px auto 10px; text-align:center;cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;width: 556px;" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y8j5IluAe4g/TykduAo1gnI/AAAAAAAAD38/K6VakbKwowU/s556/Czerwony%2BStompee%2Bdla%2Bdzieci.jpeg" alt="" id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5704123079323910770" border="0" />
```

The blog I am working with is: http://buczekmruczek.blogspot.com/2012/01/rowerkiem-przez-bedgebury-forest.html (the first photo is resized, the following not)

I would be grateful for hints and/or code samples.

Comment: Do you want to change the src string to load another image from a different source or do you want it to be changed so that the markup does not reveal the true source of the image?

Comment: Hi @GrantVS, I want the image to be loaded from a different source.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayofimgs = document.getelementsbytagname('img')

foreach arrayofimgs
   if( strpos(img.src, 'blogspot.com') )
       img.style.width='556px';
       img.style.height='';
       doSomeRegexOrManualStringManipulation(img.src, 's400', 's556')
```

Comment: Well, I did ask about javascript specifically. I do agree that pseudocode is best for algorithmic problems though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about changing the source string but to resize the images you can combine jQuery with a custom function as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   resizeImages();
 });

 function resizeImages(){
  var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName("image");
  if (!imageTags || imageTags.length <= 0)
  {
    imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  }
  if(!imageTags){
    return;
  }
  for(i = 0 ; i < imageTags.length; i++){

     imageTags[i].style.width="556px";
 imageTags[i].style.height="";
  }  
 }
</script>
<head>
<body>
<image ...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who want a copy-pastable answer, just paste this script somewhere at the end of the template:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for(i = 0 ; i < imageTags.length; i++){
    if( imageTags[i].src.indexOf('/s400/', 0)>-1 ) {
      if(imageTags[i].style.width=='400px')
    imageTags[i].style.width='556px';
      else
        imageTags[i].style.width='368px';
      imageTags[i].style.height='';
      imageTags[i].src=imageTags[i].src.replace('/s400/', '/s556/');
    }
  }
  /* ]]> */
</script>
```