# auto resize the images within the edit area

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I've tested "all" the answers i found in the internet on resizing the pictures within the blogger edit post. Some of them just resize the image dimension but **not the actual resolution** of the picture, while some of them are actually on that purpose I was looking for using javascript but...

It seems not to work.

so I was thinking maybe because the blogger updated something that it might not work anymore?

for example this solution > [JavaScript for resizing photos in Blogger posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202187/javascript-for-resizing-photos-in-blogger-posts)

and its posted in 2012.

so maybe I miss something out?
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will replace your image src size `/s72-c/` with `newSize`.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    var newSize = 500;  // this is the new image size, you can change this
        $("your img selector").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/s72-c/", "/s"+newSize+"/"));
        });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please, avoid code only answers and explain your solution.

Comment: Replace `newSize` , `your img selector` and `/s72-c/` with yours.